# Windows batch script to remove parentheses and characters inside from folder name

Tags: windows, batch, script

I have many folders that have a parentheses as part of the name. I would like a Windows batch script to recursively rename the folders without the parentheses. I only see scripts that can do it for files, but not for the folders.

**Example of folder names:**

- c:\folder\John (Williams) Doe
- c:\folder\Mike (Lee) Smith
- c:\folder\Jane Doe (Roberts)
- c:\folder\(Louis) Janet Taylor

**Change to:**

- c:\folder\John Doe
- c:\folder\Mike Smith
- c:\folder\Jane Doe
- c:\folder\Janet Taylor

I currently have the following script, but it deletes everything after the open parenthesis.

```
pushd "c:\folder\"
for /d %%i in (*.*) do for /f "delims=(" %%j in ("%%~i") do if "%%~i" neq "%%~j" ren "%%~i" "%%~nj"
popd
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Google "Bulk rename utility"

Comment: You got your slashes the wrong way around. Windows slashes are back slashes. To know if it's backwards or forwards, imagine somebody walking left to right like the way english or american goes.  The backslash looks like they are falling back. The forward sdlash looks like they are falling forward

Comment: You write "I only see scripts that can do it for text files, but not for the folder names." <--  Not just text files. You mean you only see scripts that do it for files, but not for "folders". Had you linked to such a script and shown your attempt to make it work for folders, somebody might have looked more at your question! They like it if people show research

Comment: My apologies, I was using the slashes as if this was in unix.  Yes, you are correct. I meant files, not just text files. I included the script that I have now and hopefully that would be clear enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```bat
@echo off && pushd "c:\folder\"

for %%G in (^) ^()do for /f delims^= %%i in ('dir /a:d /s /b ^| findstr "%%~G"
    ')do set "_name=%%~nxi" && cmd.exe /v:on /c rename "%%~fi" "!_name:%%~G=!"

popd
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the @Io-oI answer did not work, but help me to get it, I just need a littel fix...

```
@echo off

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

pushd "c:\folder\"

for %%G in ( ^) ) do (
    for /f delims^= %%i in ('dir /a /s /b ^| findstr "%%~G"') do (
        set "_name=%%~nxi" && cmd.exe /v:on /c rename "%%~fi" "!_name:%%~G=!"
        )
    )


for %%G in ( ^( ) do (
    for /f delims^= %%i in ('dir /a /s /b ^| findstr "%%~G"') do (
        set "_name=%%~nxi" && cmd.exe /v:on /c rename "%%~fi" "!_name:%%~G=!"
        )
    )


popd
```